# SQL select column of attributes with latest date

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple tenants and some tenants have an other expiration date, the rest in the table is for every tenant the same. I want to select the tenant with only the latest expiration date.

This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
property.scode AS "M nr",
tenant.scode AS "Contract nr",
unit.scode AS "Unit",
commamendments.DTSTART AS "Starting date",
sqft.DTDATE AS "Expiry date",
sqft.DSQFT0 AS "Area"


FROM 
property 
LEFT JOIN unit ON unit.hproperty = property.hmy
LEFT JOIN unitxref ON unitxref.hunit = unit.hmy
LEFT JOIN commamendments ON commamendments.hmy = unitxref.hamendment 
LEFT JOIN tenant ON tenant.hmyperson = commamendments.htenant
JOIN attributes ON attributes.HPROP = property.hmy
JOIN sqft ON sqft.hpointer = unit.hmy


WHERE property.scode = '481' 
AND sqft.DSQFT0 != '0'
AND ('9/30/2017 12:00:00 AM' BETWEEN  commamendments.DTSTART AND commamendments.DTEND)
ORDER BY   commamendments.DTEND`
```

As output I want a table with

```
Mnr     Contract nr      Unit     Starting date    Expiry date    Area
481       1                1      9-10-2017         12-31-2018     400
481       2                2      8-10-2017         12-31-2019     500
.....
```

What I now receive is:

```
Mnr     Contract nr      Unit     Starting date    Expiry date    Area
481       1                1      9-10-2017         12-31-2018     400
481       1                1      9-10-2017         09-20-2018     400
481       2                2      8-10-2017         12-31-2019     500
481       2                2      8-10-2017         1-31-2018      500
.....
```

Comment: Can you provide the queries that you've already attempted?

Comment: Alway tag ur DBMS . please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which RDBMS you are working on and the table schema, then you can do this:

```
SELECT t1.tenantId, t1.ExpiryDate
FROM tenants AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT tenantId, MAX(ExpiryDate) AS LatestExpiryDate
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY tenantId
) AS t1 ON t1.tenantId = t2.tenantId, t1.ExpiryDate = t2.LatestExpiryDate;
```

The inner join will give the latest date for each tenant id, and then you can join with the original query to get only those with the latest date.

(You didn't specify the table schema so I had to guess the columns' names, but I hope you got the idea).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use this, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code. I updated my question with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Row_Number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)  to find the latest record of your tenants

```
  Select * from (
    Select *,Row_number() over(Partition by Tenants order by expirationdate desc) as rn from tablea
    ) x 
    Where rn = 1
```